# C++ Searching a String Array for every instance of a user given search term.

Tags: c++, arrays, search, find

Ok. So I have an assignment that loads a file of books and their authors sequential lines. I've got the titles loading into book title array and book authors into book author array.
I need the following to happen.

Show all books and authors. <<< completed.

Show ALL books and authors from user input AUTHOR search string. << semi works

Show ALL books and authors from user input BOOK search string. << semi works

The last two are having problems by the way of

Author function.

User input : Malik

output: 0 authors found! (14 times)

Same for the title query.

I've scoured the net, read my book a million times. OK maybe not that much. Tried a hundred different versions of code and still hurting.

Any help would be great!

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//these declarations should be at file scope
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
string bookTitle  [ARRAY_SIZE];
string bookAuthor [ARRAY_SIZE];
int nob = 0;
ifstream dataBase;


// Function prototypes
int loadData(string pathName);//complete  
void showAll(int nob);
int showBooksByAuthor (int nob, string name);
int showBooksByTitle (int nob, string title);
void showChoices();

int main()
{
    string pathName;
    int x = 1;
    char menu;
    cout << "Welcome to Phil's Library Database. " << endl;
    cout << "Enter the location of the Database: (ex: c:/filename.txt ";
    cin  >> pathName;
    //read pathName and input data to arrays
    dataBase.open(pathName);
    loadData(pathName);
    //output number of files loaded
    cout << nob <<" records loaded successfully." <<endl;

    string name;
    string title;

        while(x == 1)
        {
            //prompt User for what they want to do
            cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, Search (A)uthor, Search (T)itle, (S)how All: ";
            cin  >> menu;
            switch(menu)
                {
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                    //exit out of program
                    x = 3;
                    break;
                    case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    cout << "Author's Name: ";
                    getline (cin, name, '\n');
                    //list books by author
                    showBooksByAuthor (nob,name);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 't':
                    cout << "Book Title: ";
                    getline (cin, title, '\n');
                    showBooksByTitle (nob, title);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                case 's':
                    //cout the entire documents array-ed contents
                    showAll(nob);
                    break;
            }
        }


    system("pause");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}    

int loadData(string pathName)
{
if(dataBase.is_open())
        {
            while(!dataBase.eof())
            {
                getline(dataBase, bookTitle[nob], '\n');
                getline(dataBase, bookAuthor[nob], '\n');
                nob += 1;

            }
        dataBase.clear();
        dataBase.seekg(0);
        return nob;
        }
else 
    cout << "Bad file path!"<< endl;
    return -1;
}
//showall Function
void showAll(int nob)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nob; i++)
    {
        //show all content of each array
        cout << bookTitle[i]<<endl;
        cout << bookAuthor[i]<<endl;    
    }
}
//showall books based on Author
int showBooksByAuthor (int nob, string name)
{
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nob; i++)
    {
        if (bookAuthor[i].find(name)) 
        {
            //output array location data
            cout << bookTitle[i];
            cout << "(" << bookAuthor[i] << ")" << endl;
            //add onto counter for output of successfully searched items
            x++;
        }
        cout << x << " Records found. " << endl;
    }

    return x;
}

//showall books based on Title
int showBooksByTitle (int nob, string title)
{
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nob; i++)
    {
        if (bookAuthor[i].find(title)) 
        {
            //output array location data
            cout << bookTitle[i];
            cout << "(" << bookAuthor[i] << ")" << endl;
            //add onto counter for output of successfully searched items
            x++;
        }
        cout << x << " Records found. " << endl;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you learn about `struct`?  The way this is usually done is to have a struct that has an author and title, and create an array of the struct.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear, especially the `book` search.  You search for a book and then display the author of the book.  Is that it?  Or do you search for the book, find the author, and then list all of the author's other books?  Or do you search for any book that has that title?...

Comment: Havent Learned structs yet. That is next week unfortunately and my instructor stated that all you will need for the assignment is arrays do to this week being "arrays" week.

Comment: As for the requirements it should work like : you search for an author , out put would be the titles and the author of all of the books the author contributed in. The file contents look like                     Objects First with Java
Barnes and Kolling`
Game Development Essentials
Novak
The Game Maker's Apprentice
Overmars
C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis...
Malik
C++ Programming Lab Manual
Scholl
Beginning LINUX Programming
Stones and Matthew
C++ Programming: Program Design Including...
D. S. Malik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this page, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/, and this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/, the find() method on the String returns -1 when there is no match.

`if ( some_num )` is true whenever `some_num` is non-zero, including -1, where `some_num` is any expression.

Read the find documentation carefully to understand how it can be used to check for a match.

Answer (score 0):

1) The `find` function is not necessary.  All you need to do is use `==`.

2) For the title, you should be testing the `bookTitle` array, not `bookAuthor`.

```
  int showBooksByAuthor (int nob, string name)
  {
      // ...
      // Search for author
      if ( bookAuthor[i] == name)
      {
        // name found
      }
      // ...
   }

   // Search for title
   int showBooksByTitle (int nob, string title)
   {
      //...
      if (bookTitle[i] == title)
      {
         // title found
      }
      //...
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul I tried that prior to posting my question but it only finds the first instance of the string. This is mainly where im struggling finding say "Malik" and only getting ---->Objects 
C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis...
Malik
and not this one as well---->
C++ Programming: Program Design Including...
D. S. Malik